# Auto relacionamento com Entity Framework 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Como faço um Auto relacionamento com EF Core 2.2?

Eu encontrei um link que ensina fazer com EF, mas no EF não tem o método WithOptional.

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? MenuId { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<Menu> SubMenu { get; set; }
 }

 modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>()
        .HasMany(x => x.SubMenu)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.MenuId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A configuração para auto relacionamento é o seguinte conforme a sua classe `Menu`:

```
x.HasMany(k => k.SubMenu)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.MenuId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(k => k.Id);
```

ou seja, deve informar qual campo se refere a chave primária e qual é a chave estrangeira que o `framework` vai carregar conforme a relação. Tem realmente a diferença na versão anterior onde no caso é um `HasMany(k => k.SubMenu)` que é a coleção de `Menu` (`SubMenu`) e no método `WithOne` não precisa informar nada.

Completa:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("Menus");

            x.HasKey(k => k.Id);
            x.Property(k => k.Id)
                .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

            x.Property(k => k.Title)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            x.Property(k => k.MenuId);

            x.HasMany(k => k.SubMenu)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.MenuId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(k => k.Id);

        });
```

Para carregar menu e submenu faça o seguinte código:

```
using (DbContextDatabase t = new DbContextDatabase())
{
     var m0 = t.Menu
            .Where(x => x.MenuId == null)
            .Include(x => x.SubMenu)
            .ToList();
}
```