# Relacionamento One-To-One com a mesma tabela Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Não sei como realizar o relacionamento um pra um na mesma tabela no `Entity Framework`.

***Exemplo:***

```
namespace cruddef.Models
{
    public class Document
    {
        public int DocumentID { get; set; }
        public int SourceDocumentID { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer, preciso relacionar a tabela `Document` com ela mesma, utilizando a chave `SourceDocumentID` com a `DocumentID`, Isso no documento de configuração do `EF` e preciso que isso aqui funcione:

```
public virtual Document DOCUMENT_SOURCE { get; set; }
```

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349636/auto-relacionamento-com-entity-framework-2-2/349745#349745

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Relacionamento 1 para 1 com Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37944/relacionamento-1-para-1-com-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma forma de isso dar certo que é um auto relacionamento **1** para **1**, não sei qual é o seu real objetivo de fazer assim, talvez existe formas melhores, mas, eu acabei fazendo um exemplo minimo e funciona, porque, nas relações do `Entity Framework` sempre existe a navegação em lista e nesse caso não ([exemplo em lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349636/auto-relacionamento-com-entity-framework-2-2/349745#349745)).

*Observações:*

- para que isso funcione no item que vai ser a chave estrangeira da tabela deve ser do tipo `null`.
- configurar esse campo da chave estrangeira com `[ForeignKey("DOCUMENT_SOURCE")]` do `namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` nesse momento está configurando o auto - relacionamento.
- exemplo minimo:

  ```
  namespace cruddef.Models
  {
      public class Document
      {
          public int DocumentID { get; set; }

          [ForeignKey("DOCUMENT_SOURCE")]
          public int? SourceDocumentID { get; set; }
          public virtual Document DOCUMENT_SOURCE { get; set; }
      }  
  }
  ```

---

No exemplo criado por mim ficou assim:

```
namespace CslAppEFAutoOneToOne.Models
{
   public class Document
   {
      public int DocumentId { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("SourceDocument")]
      public int? SourceDocumentId { get; set; }
      public virtual Document SourceDocument { get; set; }
   }

   public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
   {
      public DatabaseContext()
         : base("Server=.\\SqlExpress;Database=TestOneToOne;User Id=sa;Password=senha;")
      {
         Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
      }

      public DbSet<Document> Document { get; set; }    
   }
}
```

Utilizando:

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    Document d1 = new Document()
    {
       Title = "Document 1"
    };

    Document d2 = new Document()
    {
       SourceDocumentId = d1.DocumentId,
       SourceDocument = d1,
       Title = "Document 2"
    };
    db.Document.Add(d1); //inserindo documento 1
    db.Document.Add(d2); //inserindo documento 2 relacionado com 1
    db.SaveChanges(); // salvando 

    var doc1 = db.Document.AsNoTracking()
       .Include("SourceDocument")
       .Where(x => x.DocumentId == 2)
       .FirstOrDefault(); // filtro e seleção da relação.
}
```

Nesse exemplo de como utilizar foi inserido um registro e o outro relacionado com o primeiro e na pesquisa buscando essa relação.